# Metaphor/Analogies for Rings and Fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

What kind of analogies or "metaphors" to "real-life things" for rings and fields are there, if any? I'm studying for a final, was just wondering if there's anything concrete to help me wrap my head around these concepts. I understand the mathematical definitions, but I'm also having trouble "visualizing" them.

For example, someone used a language translation as an analogy for isomorphisms and other morphisms (like how an isomorphism is a perfect 1-1 language translation, while homomorphisms may translate from one lang. to another, but not necessarily back to the same word). Is there anything along that line for rings and fields? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think real world examples are the way to go here. But mathematical examples are definitely useful. Rings are basically generalisations of $\mathbb Z$. We can add and multiply. There is a $0$ and a $1$. We can't necessarily divide. A ring is a set $R$ where we have operations of addition and multiplication, with a $0$ and a $1$. $\mathbb Z$ is Euclidean domain because of Euclid's algorithm. It is a PID because we can find the highest common factor of any two integers. And that it is a UFD is one of the first things you prove in a number theory course.